# Should SetCustomStatus() be called when orchestration is replayed?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Do I need to check if context is being replayed when calling `SetCustomStatus()`:

```
if (!context.IsReplaying)
{
    context.SetCustomStatus("My status");
}
```

Is there any benefit of doing this? I couldn't find any mention of this in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-custom-orchestration-status).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this, but I wouldn't recommend it since it would effectively make your orchestrator function non-deterministic. It's very important that an orchestrator function perform the exact same logic on each replay.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints):

> Orchestrator code must be deterministic. It will be replayed multiple times and must produce the same result each time.

The primary exception to this is logging since that has no effect on the behavior of the orchestration itself.

Comment: BTW, would that be possible to inject instance of `ILogger` which checks IsReplaying by itself?

Comment: @oderibas possibly - we'd need to look into whether an extension can change the `ILogger` which gets injected into function code. I recommend opening an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues) if you'd like to see this feature implemented.

Comment: I see that there's already issue about this but it is closed: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/170